# Как в richTextBox показать 2 (или больше) переменных?

Tags: c#

Или: какой другой элемент форм использовать для этого?

Например, у меня такой код:

```
        richTextBox2.Text = "Количество слов в тексте: " + text.Length;
        char[] b = text.ToCharArray();
        richTextBox2.Text = "Количество знаков в тексте: " + b.Length;
```

Но показывает только последнюю строку.

Comment: richTextBox2.Text += "Количество знаков в тексте: " + b.Length;    
Ну, и перенос строки добавить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте класс StringBuilder для формирования строк. Затем передавайте значение переменной этого класса в нужный текстбокс.

```
char[] b = text.ToCharArray();
StringBuilder strText = new StringBuilder();
strText .Append("Количество слов в тексте: ");
strText .Append(text.Length);
strText .Append("Количество знаков в тексте: ");
strText .Append(b.Length);

richTextBox2.Text = strText.ToString();
```

Именно такой способ является лучшим, когда вы обрабатываете строки, ведь обычные переменные класса string являются неизменяемыми, что является минусом при большом количестве операций.